# KDE5 Plasma Launcher does not find some files, but baloosearch does - how to fix?

Tags: linux, kde, file-search, kde-plasma-5, search-indexing

The Plasma Launcher and KRunner of KDE5 have a plugin providing indexed file search. To the best of my knowledge, they use baloo as their backend.

In my literature directory, I have many files named by the pattern

```
YEAR - AUTHOR - TITLE.pdf
```

Now I often find that I cannot find some of the files in the results. However, it doesn't seem to be an issue of baloo. For instance

```
2011 Smith
```

will give the paper `~/Documents/Papers/2011 - Smith, et al. - New Research.pdf` in Plasma Launcher, KRunner and `baloo search 2011 Smith` equally. However, when I type

```
2009 Jones
```

I will get the paper `~/Documents/Papers/2009 - Jones, et al. - Previous Research.pdf` from `baloosearch 2009 Jones`, but *not* in KRUnner or Plasma Launcher. Even more confusingly, after I opened the file manually from the directory, the search query

```
2009
```

now gives it as the first result, while `2009 Jones` still returns nothing.

I already tried resetting baloo with

```
balooctl stop
sleep 10
rm /home/kdbauer/.local/share/baloo/index
rm /home/kdbauer/.local/share/baloo/index-lock
sleep 10
balooctl start
```

but that helps only if baloo is stuck in a manner such that `baloosearch` doesn't find the result either.

So I was wondering: Am I wrong about baloo being used? Or is there some unnecessary caching taking place? Is there any way to diagnose the issue?

The issue has been recurring and isn't resolved by reboots or waiting. It came up yesterday both with a newly added document, and with one I had since months and, due to the missing search result, thought I hadn't obtained yet.

The device is Running openSUSE Leap 15.1.